# Find words start with consonants that near to each other

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to write a regular expression that finds words starting with consonants that are near to each other.

Here is what I come up with:

```
\b[^aeiou0-9\W][a-z]+\s[^aeiou0-9\W][a-z]+\b
```

but the issue is that I need to check before and after word.

For example:

```
Vowels and consonants are sounds, not letters. Depending on your accent and how thinly you slice them, there are about 20 vowels and 24 consonants.
```

Result:

```
how thinly 
you slice
```

Expected result:

```
how thinly
thinly you 
you slice
```

Comment: I didn't understand what "consonants that are near to each other" means.

Comment: words that start with consonants and they are near to each other or next to each other @mkrieger1

Comment: Words such as "Vowels", "not", or "letters"?

Comment: You need to define "near".

Comment: all characters except vowel  @mkrieger1

Comment: next to each other @CaptainCaveman

Comment: Why are the words "how" and "you" in the expected result? Why are "them" and "there" not in the expected result?

Comment: that was because the comma @mkrieger1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b([^aeiou0-9\W][a-z]+)\s(?=([^aeiou0-9\W][a-z]+))`

Example:  https://regex101.com/r/tSblEq/1

This is based off of the rules in your pattern.  Instead of matching `<word><space><word>` directly, it's matching `<word><space><lookahead word>`.  It's then grouping the `<word>` and the `<lookahead word>` into groups 1 & 2 respectively.

Because the lookahead doesn't consume the characters, each word is evaluated individually for a following word.

Result:

```
Match 1 Group 1: how
Match 1 Group 2: thinly

Match 2 Group 1: thinly
Match 2 Group 2: you

Match 3 Group 1: you
Match 3 Group 2: slice
```

Edit to better demonstrate matching directly vs lookahead:

Direct:

```
how thinly you slice
         ^
```

The engine is left at the end of the match.  'thinly' cannot be evaluated.

Using lookahead:

```
how thinly you slice
    ^
```

Because the match only consumed "how" and the space after it, the engine is now left at the beginning of the word "thinly".

Comment: can we return each number of matches as one sentence (such as how thinly)

Comment: Short answer is no.  To explain, the first words of the sentence are "how thinly".  If you are matching directly, you consume all the letters.  When the regular expression engine goes to make the next match, it starts from the end of "thinly".  When you use the lookahead, you don't consume the letters of "thinly" meaning the next match can now start at the end of "how" instead.   You can take these pairs of matches and combine them back together in post processing for evaluation.